# How to get the 'number' passed to a function

Tags: vim

I want to write a function in `vim` that acts differently if it has been the recipient of a number, for example, in `10d` "d" receives the number "10". Here is what I have thus far:

```
function ParenHandler()
    if <number_passed>
        echo 'yes'
    else
        echo 'no'
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap    (   :call ParenHandler()<CR>
```

How do I get the "number_passed" ? Additionally, what is the help keyword for all the available 'params' that are passed to a function (interally or otherwise)?

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#a:0

Comment: See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#41.7 about defining a function with arguments and using those arguments.  See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#41.11 about writing a `vim` plug-in.

Comment: @phd I added an answer -- it's not about passing optional args but in grabbing an arg that is part of the vim internal-vars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is stored internally in `v:count`:

> `v:count`     The count given for the last Normal mode command.  Can be used
> to get the count before a mapping.  Read-only.  Example: >
> :map _x :echo "the count is " . v:count.

If no number is passed to it, then `v:count` is set to zero. You can then do the mapping as follows:

```
nnoremap    <expr> (    (v:count == 0) ? '(' : 'j'
nnoremap    <expr> )    (v:count == 0) ? ')' : 'k'
```

Comment: This posting has a bit more information about v:count, Repeat n time a mapping starting with a count  https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7877/repeat-n-time-a-mapping-starting-with-a-count